# How to get access token in social auth in android and how to reuse them

Tags: android, integration, socialauth

I know this question is already asked and answered but that didn't help me. I am working on integration of few social apps like Facebook and Twitter by using social auth lib. I have successfully implemented them by following code:

```
public class SignUp extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private EditText email_mEditText,password_mEditText;
SocialAuthAdapter socialAuthAdapter;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
    socialAuthAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
    socialAuthAdapter.authorize(SignUp.this, Provider.FACEBOOK);
    socialAuthAdapter.signOut(this, Provider.FACEBOOK.toString());
```

With this code I am able to open Facebook to authorize but I want to get the access token. I tried the following code to get the access token in my activity:

```
    socialAuthAdapter.getCurrentProvider().getAccessGrant().getKey();
```

However, this crashes the app and shows a `NullPointerException`.

`03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405): Process: com.technearby.app.main, PID: 19405
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at com.technearby.app.main.SignUp.onClick(SignUp.java:107)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: Could you add the exception to your question? Only then we know what it's pointing at.

Comment: @Shishdem 03-12 16:14:37.278: E/AndroidRuntime(19405): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: The whole stacktrace would be nice, now we still can't see what the exception is pointing at. EG what is "null".

Comment: getCurrentProvider() is null  @Shishdem

Comment: @Shishdem plz check the exception ..i call this code on a click button

Comment: As replied in the answer, you never instantiate a provider nor add those to your adapter.

Comment: should you have more problems please elaborate in this same question page. If my answer below was helpful to you, please consider it marking as the answer so others have benefit from your question and my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add providers yourself to the adapter. For example, `adapter.addProvider(Provider.FACEBOOK, R.drawable.facebook);`.